# Where are are IdentityUsers uploaded to the database?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I have created a ASP.net core web app with user authentication. The user authentication has been auto-implemented and it works like a charm. However, I need to do 2 things:

-Add a text field 'Name' to the user registration

-Write a record into another (custom-made) table when `AspNetUsers` is written to.

However, I can't seem to find where (meaning in what file/method) either of these things can be done.

I tried and debugged the web app, but it didn't help.
As I expect that `IdentityUsers` are written to the data base using `DbContext.Add`, I also searched for that but didn't help either.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following article explains everything: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio .